# How to save outlook email attachments with Python, on Virtal Desktop (VMWare)

Tags: python, outlook, vmware, pywin32

The below code works on my W10 laptop, but not on my w10 or w7 virtual desktop (VMWare).

It reads emails and save attachments from a specific sender to a shared network drive, and moves the email to a sub folder.

I guess I need to change the line:

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

any pointers much appreciated.

```
import win32com.client
import re
path='//shared_drive/StatementFiles/'
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) 
donebox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).folders("Bank").folders("Statements")
messages = inbox.Items# get the first email
message = messages.GetLast()
sender_name = 'sender@email.com'
i = 1
while i < 100:
    message = messages.GetLast()
    try:
        current_sender = str(message.Sender).lower()
        current_subject = str(message.Subject)
        messagedate = message.senton
        if re.search(sender_name, current_sender) != None:
            print(current_subject) # verify the subject
            print(current_sender)  # verify the sender
            attachments = message.Attachments
            attachment = attachments.Item(1)
            attachment_name = str(attachment).lower()
            attachment.SaveASFile(path + attachment_name)
            att_path=path + attachment_name
            message.UnRead = False
            message.Move(donebox)
            current_sender = str(message.Sender).lower()
            current_subject = str(message.Subject)
            print(f'Email moved.')
        message = messages.GetNext()
    except:
        message = messages.GetNext()
    i += 1
```

I don't have Python installed on eiter of the virtual desktops, still waiting for it to be packaged, and I don't have the permissions to install, so on the virtual desktops I am running an exe file created with PyInstaller - again, this exe works correctly on my laptop.
Running this exe via cmd prompts returns no message or error.

Comment: Can you step through the code one line at a time to see where it fails?

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, just updated the post to explain that I don't have Python installed on the VMWare desktops so running an exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly running this on a virtual desktop you need to reverse the order, so instead of going for GetLast, using GetFirst resolved this.
Did hit another snag where Outlook brings up a message to allow an programme to emails, of either 1, 2, 5 or 10 minutes.
I couldn't find a way to deactivate this on our VMWare, so have decided to switch to VBA, which is now doing what I need.
Frustrating, but at least it's a solution.